# append character after every word in implode

Tags: php, append, implode

I have an `array $names(me, myself, I);`

I want to output:

> me,; myself,; I;

I tried `echo implode (",", $names) . ";"`

ouput is

> me, myself, I;

how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Then change `,` separator to `,;` :

```
echo implode (",;", $names) . ";";
```

#### [Demo](https://eval.in/164656)

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
 echo implode (",;", $names);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
$arr = array('me','myself','I');

$names = implode(',;',$arr).';';

echo $names;
```

**[Demo](https://ideone.com/OD2yvN)**